# Is there a way to dynamically generate output schema in Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am using google cloud data fusion to ingest a CSV file from AWS, apply directives, and store the resultant file in GCS. Is there a way to dynamically generate the output schema of the CSV file for Wrangler? I am uploading the input path, directives, output schema as a macro to the argument setter. I can see options only to import and export output schema.

Comment: In order to investigate further, I need some more information. Would you mind elaborating a bit more on what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve when you say "generate the output schema of the csv file"?

Comment: I'm currently creating a Datafusion pipeline that ingests a csv from AWS, apply transforms and load it into a GCS bucket. I have created a macro for the output schema so that I could pass a JSON file representing the output schema during runtime since the schema changes for every file. Is there any other way to auto detect the schema of csv input file(like when we load csv files in BigQuery) and pass it to the output schema field?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to get the output schema dynamically since the output schema can be wildly different as a result of a parse directive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Also, wanted to know if there is any restriction on the CSV encoding format that can be used in Data Fusion? I am having inconsistent data in the output file when ingesting ISO-8859-1 encoded files, while ASCII encoded files are just fine.